# JAX-WS web service with Source return type on Websphere

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, jaxb, websphere, jax-ws

I am migrating an old JAX-WS 2.1 web service from JBoss 4 to Websphere 7.  Most of the `@WebMethod` components all look like this:

```
@WebMethod
public Source someMethod(){
    Source source = null;

    try{
            source = ServiceActions.someMethodWorker();
    }
    catch( Throwable throwable ){
            source = ServiceActions.handleThrowable("Error occured in method someMethod", throwable );
    }
    return source;
}
```

`ServiceActions.someMethodWorker()` usually goes off and fetches that data populates a JAXB structure, marshalls into XML and returns a `StreamSource` of the XML like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance();
Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
marshaller.marshal(someJaxBObjectHierarchy, byteArrayOutputStream);

return new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()));
```

This web service runs just fine on JBoss 4 (with the Jax-WS and JaxB libraries) and GlassFish 3.1, but Websphere 7 keeps giving me the following error any time I use a client against the web service:

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource nor any of its super class is known to this context.]
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:178)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:111)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)
```

At first look this seems to be the JAXB type binding problem; however, I've added `@XmlSeeAlso(StreamSource.class)` everywhere, and I still get the error.

Would someone know why this is failing on WebSphere 7?

Thanks!

**Edit/Solution:**  The solution is to use `byte[]` return type instead of `Source`

GlassFish and JBoss were doing something extra compared to the JAX-WS specification which led me to believe that `Source` return type was OK.

Instead of my methods returning `new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()))` they now just return `byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()`

Comment: I am not sure what the solution is, but it sounds like a bug in WebSphere 7.  For this use case since you are returning a `Source` the JAX-WS implementation does not need to leverage a JAXB impl to do the binding.  Adding an `@XmlSeeAlso(StreamSource.class)` is the opposite of what you want to do, as it will force JAXB to be brought in, and it will complain about the `Source` class.

Comment: If this is the case, would there be a way to turn off JAXB for the endpoints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

javax.xml.transform.Source is not a valid return type for a normal JAX-WS service endpoint interface (SEI). If you want to do that (and be compliant with JAX-WS) you need to use a service that is implemented as a javax.xml.ws.Provider (see the corresponding docs). If JBoss or GlassFish support Source as a parameter or return type in a normal SEI, then that's a proprietary extension.

Comment: I was wondering about this and have poured over the docs about `@WebService` but I haven't found anything to suggest it was an invalid return type.  Where did you find this?  (I may just be blind)

Comment: Section 3.4 of the JAX-WS 2.1 spec defines as a criteria for a valid SEI that "All method parameters and return types are compatible with the JAXB 2.0 Java to XML Schema mapping definition", and that is further explained in subsequent sections. It turns out that JAXB actually maps javax.xml.transform.Source to xs:base64Binary by default. Is that the intention here and is that what JBoss and GlassFish do?

Comment: That was it!  I changed all my endpoints to return type of `byte[]` (xs:base64Binary maps to byte) instead of `Source` and all is working.  As to what GlassFish and JBoss are doing - I have no idea!